# serving xhtml + mathml to firefox and IE

Tags: apache, xhtml, mathml

Firefox requires xhtml extension for mathml but IE will not display pages with xhtml extension (it displays a download dialog box instead).

I have tried apache content negotiation like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteRule \.xhtml$ - [T=text/html]
```

but IE seems only to care about the extension.  I have tried this on my local server where mod_rewrite is installed.

Comment: It seems IE is relatively happy if I use the .html extension and everyone else is satisfied with  AddType application/xhtml+xml .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this works:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*MSIE.*
RewriteRule \.html$ - [T=application/xhtml+xml]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteRule \.html$ - [T=text/html]
</ifmodule>
```

If it weren't for internet explorer, I'd know so much less about all sorts of things!

Comment: You also wouldn't *need* to know those things because you'd be happily working on your website. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't support XHTML (except [marketing](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/xhtml2-html5-q-and-a/) XHTML) or MathML (without a plugin).

If you want to use MathML — forget about unadulterated IE support for your pages.